# How many 3-digit numbers are there, for which the product of their digits is more than 2 but less than 7?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

One  way to solve these types of questions is to go one by one and figure out all the possibilities starting from 111. And I have found till now 19 possibilities for this question. But the answer is somewhat different. It seems that I might have missed some of the possibilities.
I was wondering if there is any other way to approach these types of questions that makes sure that I do not miss any of the possibilities. Any simpler or logical or diagrammatical way to solve these types of questions, that would be really helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: By my count there are $21$. Ignoring order, the only possible combinations of digits are $113,114,115,116,122$ and, $123$. Each of the first $5$ can be ordered in $3$ different ways, and the last one can be ordered in $6$ different ways.

Answer (score 1):

**Hin**t:let the number be $\overline{xyz}$

Now if $x\cdot y\cdot z=p$ where $p=3,5$ then we $x,y,z$ must be a permutation of $1,1,p$ Hence number of such numbers is $2\cdot \frac{3!}{2!}$

Now if $x\cdot y\cdot z=4,6$ then $x,y,z$ must be a permutation of either $1,1,4$ or $2,2,1$ or $1,1,6$ or $2,3,1$ .Each of which the number of cases can be easily found......

Answer (score 0):

A more organized approach is to note that $2^3=8>7$, so the only combinations that will work (in any order of digits) are $11x$ for $x \in \{3,4,5,6\}$, and also $122$ and $123$.

Now you must determine how many numbers are contributed by each. For example, $123$ contributes $3!=6$ to the overall sum.